# Having issue with Datatables possibly because of turbolinks

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatable

Working on a rails application, in assests pipeline i have a file named `questions.js.coffee` with content

```
jQuery ->
  $('#questions').dataTable
```

with this file datatables is not working and no errors, just showing the same simple table.

I created another file with name `questions.js`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#questions').DataTable();
} );
```

with this datatables are working as expected.

Comment: `.dataTable` and `.DataTable` ... feel difference?

Comment: Oh thanks man, i also forget to put brackets, so now it is `$('#questions').DataTable()` and perfectly working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a typo as @Малъ-Скрылевъ said now `questions.js.coffee` is working as expected.

```
jQuery ->
  $('#questions').DataTable()
```